# Print matching result

Tags: php

I am trying to make matching of headers and print result.

My goal is to print green color for each user on specific day in a month if the user has record for that day in a db, if not print red.

In table header I print date for specific month.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            <?php 
                $date = '2016-11-01';
                $end = '2016-11-' . date('t', strtotime($date)); //get end date of month
                while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
                    $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
                    $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
                    $day_month = date('m', strtotime($date));

                    $months[]=$day_name = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
                    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
                    echo "<td>$day_name <br/> $day_num | $day_month</td>";
                 }
              ?>
         </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I got this part right. Then I print all users from database by using while loop.

```
$users = "SELECT UposlenikID, UposlenikIme  FROM uposlenici WHERE Status = 0";

    $q = $conn->query($users);
    $zapisi ="SELECT UposlenikID, date(VrijemeZapisa) as datum FROM users_checked";

    $qq = $conn -> query($zapisi);

<tbody>
    <?php 
        $i=1; 
        while ($r=$q->fetch()) {    
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php  echo $i++;  ?>
        </td>
        <td>
           <?=$r['UposlenikIme']; ?>                  
        </td>
        <?php
        foreach ($months as $mjesec) { 

              $sql = "SELECT Id, UposlenikID FROM user_checked WHERE TimeStamp = $mjesec ";                     

               $query = $conn -> query($sql);
        <td>
            // here I need to print matching I was using for each loop
           <?php } ?>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <?php }  // end while loop  ?>
</tbody>
```

I was wondering how to match now and if is possible doing things this way.

In db table user_checked I have inserted all users.

Table structure Uposlenici

```
UposlenikID      UPOSLENIKIME        STATUS

1                  UserName             0 
2                  UserName2            0
```

Table structure user_checked

```
Id        UposlenikID        TimeStamp             Command       

1           3           2016-11-27 13:22:14        CheckIN
2           4           2016-11-28 13:22:17        CheckIN
3           5           2016-11-29 13:22:20        CheckIN
4           6           2016-11-30 13:22:24        CheckIN
```

At the end I should get table like this:

[image]

Comment: Please explain your question. By 'now' you mean current date ?.

Comment: What database system are you using - is this PDO?

Comment: You'll need to modify `WHERE TimeStamp = $mjesec` so it does not have second accuracy. The first clause `Timestamp` contains dates and times, whereas `$mjesec` is probably a timestamp set to midnight, and so will rarely match. Try `WHERE DATE(Timestamp) = $mjesec` instead, this will round your timestamp to the date only.

Comment: You may need to convert $mjesec to a date as well, what format is it in?

Comment: Lastly it looks like you need code at your `// here I need to print matching I was using for each loop` placeholder, and adding something here to test the output of the query would be the best place to start.